# In Server Images are not responding in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I am having issue that with this alias when I am pointing to a server at that time images are not showing.
My configuration of server for the application is

```
        Alias /questions /app/xyz/public
        PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p327@abcd/ruby

        #RailsBaseURI /beingme
        RailsBaseURI /questions
        <Directory /app/xyz/public>
                RailsEnv production
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Please provide me the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define one more Alias for assets

```
Alias /assets /app/xyz/public/assets
```

It will work for you, I hope.